# Why are minor introns bounded by nucleotides AT-AC, where T is not normally in RNA?

Tags: rna, introns

Major intron boundary nucleotides are GU-AG. Minor intron boundary nucleotides are AT-AC. Why does the former use RNA Uracil and the latter use DNA thymine? Since introns are in the primary RNA transcript, shouldn't both be RNA and use U rather than T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not unusual for RNA sequences to be reported with T instead of U; the writer is reporting the cDNA sequence instead of the RNA sequence.  In RNA at the boundary of the minor intron, there is a uracil.  In the following page, the writers follow the oft-used convention of describing RNA with T instead of U (writing the cDNA sequence).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_spliceosome